# javascript : creating elements on first click and deleting the created element on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div in my page that I will be using to generate a p tag in another div with class added to it.

```js
function creatorfunction() {
  var u94 = document.getElementById("box").getAttribute("custom-data");
  parau94 = document.createElement("p");
  parau94.innerHTML = u94;
  parau94.className = "u94cl";
  creation = document.getElementById("generator");
  creation.appendChild(parau94);
}
```

```css
#generator {
  background-color: #29BF97;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

#box {
  background-color: #29BF97;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" onclick="creatorfunction()" custom-data="you just clicked me"> click me </div>
<div id="generator">
</div>
```

Here is what next i am trying to achieve.
when I click on "click me" it create the p tag but now I want to delete the same p tag If I click on "click me " again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why are you adding jquery if you're not using for selecting and click events?

Anyway, you need to add a tiny plugin to handle the toggle functionality.

Then you call `clickToggle` which takes 2 functions and switches between them on each click.

```js
//clickToggle plugin
(function($) {
  $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
    var funcs = [func1, func2];
    this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
    this.click(function() {
      var data = $(this).data();
      var tc = data.toggleclicked;
      $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
      data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
    });
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));
//end plugin


$('#box').clickToggle(function() {
  creatorfunction();
}, function() {
  $('#generator').children().first().remove(); //removes the first child from #generator
});


function creatorfunction() {
  var u94 = document.getElementById("box").getAttribute("custom-data");
  parau94 = document.createElement("p");
  parau94.innerHTML = u94;
  parau94.className = "u94cl";
  creation = document.getElementById("generator");
  creation.appendChild(parau94);
}
```

```css
#generator {
  background-color: #29BF97;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

#box {
  background-color: #29BF97;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" custom-data="you just clicked me"> click me </div>
<div id="generator">
</div>
```

Comment: awesome @miro.  jquery was used for something else I just forgot to remove it while editing the snippet

Comment: well my solution requires jquery. If you remove it, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with javascript

```js
function creatorfunction() {
  var u94 = document.getElementById("box").getAttribute("custom-data");
  parau94 = document.createElement("p");


  parau94.innerHTML = u94;
  parau94.className = "u94cl";



  creation = document.getElementById("generator");


  if (creation.firstChild.nextElementSibling === null) {
    creation.appendChild(parau94);
  } else {
    creation.removeChild(creation.lastChild);
  }

}
```

```css
#generator {
  background-color: #29BF97;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

#box {
  background-color: #29BF97;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="creatorfunction()" custom-data="you just clicked me"> click me </div>
<div id="generator">
</div>
```